# Do vs. does in a statement

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, do-support

In the statement "Editorial use of images do not require a model release." which form of do/does would be correct? Should the verb agree with images (as in "images do not require..."), or with editorial use (as in "editorial use does not require...")?

Comment: *Use* is the subject. *Of* is there for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

It should agree with editorial use. Therefore, the sentence should be "Editorial use of images **does** not require a model release."